# ThreeJS export bones misalignment

Tags: export, bones, geometry, three.js

I have been trying to get the three.js exporter to export my bones and animations for days and I always run into the same wall: the bones are rotated clockwise by 90 degrees compared to the model. I am aware this issue could be in the exporter but I can't find a single person posting about that online, so I am wondering if anyone knows why this could be happening and whether this is something I am doing?

This is how it looks in blender:

[image]

And this is how it looks in THREE.js:

[image]

*(The green-blue lines represent the bones here, and it is about halfway through its animation - separately, the bones and geometry seem correct, but at an angle to each other instead of aligned)*

I have tried a number of times from scratch, manually assigned the vertices to the vertex groups, manually creating the bones, etc... But every time the bones are off. The bones themselves are functioning perfectly fine, except that they now twist the shape at an angle, which means my animations get distorted big time. I just want to find out *what* I am missing as nobody else seems to have any issues with this on the internet... Gratitude to all who can help!

Comment: Hi. Could you add a reference to the addon you are using ?

Comment: @lemon Its the threejs exporter (included in the threejs extras at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender )

Comment: You should also give a blend file as an example to facilitate finding your issue and some internet site where three.js can be used for testing.

Comment: @lemon I have a file available here: http://somethinghere.net/random/armature-threejs-bones-misalignement.zip -  hope it can help anyone finding an answer!

Comment: I add the problem but I don't have it anymore and I don't know why. Hypothesis : I used the "save settings" button... Could you have a try ?

Comment: I use the save settings in the exporter all the time to make sure I don't forget what settings I was using and whether it made a difference... If you mean that button, it doesn't make a difference. It's the settings you used that probably did!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44092/discussion-between-lemon-and-somethinghere).

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved after trying it again, even though I feel I made no changes since last time I tried. Thanks to @lemon for talking me through this. If anyone can pinpoint exactly why I had this effect, you are still eligible for bounty today but the issue has disappeared on my end.